# Azure API Management and OAuth2 - use a single AD AppReg for multiple API's, or a single AD AppReg for each API?

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I'm currently in the process of setting up a single instance of API Management. I have a project that is going to comprise of x4 API's that are all going to be required for OAuth2 authentication.(I have a single AD tenant).

I've been following this (rather bewildering) guide on getting API Management set up with OAuth2...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

...it specifies that you create an Azure Active Directory App Registration for...

1) The API (single API?)

2) Client that accesses the API

My question is...I know I only potentially need 1 client App Registration, but do I need x4 App Registrations for each API, or can I just use the single one and have all 4 API's use that single one?

I've tested this and it seems to work fine, I'm just wondering if I am missing a trick here and potentially painting myself into a corner later on.

I am after some best practice here on what is the right thing to do. It is less administration to have a single App Registration that can look after x4 (or more) API's, but will that cause issues later on?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you don't technically need 1 app registration for each webapi or each app. but it's considered best practice for security and separation of apis and access to such apis, also makes it easier to audit and monitor.

However, there is nothing technically stopping you if you just want 1 app registration to handle all 4 apis. and even the client for that matter.

For example, you will have a harder time controlling access per API, eg if you want user A to be able to access api A but not B. then it's much more difficult. also, security wise, all the other apis would be able to access eachothers endpoints if you were to only have 1 app registration.

Manageability also comes into play. if for example you wanted some specific thing for one of the apps in the app registration, scopes/roles/etc. combining them would make it more difficult to do so.

Bottom line, create one for each web api under 90-95% of situations, it's best practice, and can potentially save you headaches later on.

Hope that gives you a bit of insight